# Check rendered text with enzyme

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using react-native and I want to test some functionality.

I want to check when I insert some text to the component like: "barak walk".

1. It changes to "BARAK WALK".
2. when it's too long compare it to "BARAK WALK...".

I don't know how to check it with enzyme( i prepare don't use snapshot this time)

Code:

```
export default ({ text }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={cardText}>
          {text}
        </Text>
      </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  box: {
    height: 160,
    width: 160,
  },
  cardText: {
    color: Colors().ALWAYS_WHITE,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 12,
    fontFamily: AleckFonts.SANS_MEDIUM,
    letterSpacing: 0.4,
    lineHeight: 15,
    padding: 6,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
});
```

I tried this one but it doesn't render the text:

```
test('Should check if text shown as expected', () => {
  const receivedText = 'barak walk';
  const expectedText = 'BARAK WALK';
  const wrapper = shallow(<Card text={receivedText} />);
  const textView = wrapper.find(Text).children();
  expect(textView.text()).toBe(expectedText);
});
```

Comment: Can you check what's the value for `textView`? perhaps if you do `expect(textView).toBe(expectedText);`, it might work..

Comment: @nishkaush, it doesn't work :/

Comment: any luck figuring out the value for `textView`?

Comment: @nishkaush, no i get this error  Expected: "TRADE-IN ELIGIBLE"
    Received: "trade-in eligible"

Comment: Could you try - `wrapper.find(Text).children`, don't invoke children as a function, just reference it

Answer (score 1):

Few things to try:

(1) `Don't use children at all`

```js
  const textView = wrapper.find(Text);  // <----take out children prop
  expect(textView.text()).to.equal(expectedText);
```

> Also because you are using CSS to change the casing of the text, it will still render as lowercase.

Example -  `barak walk` is rendering as `barak walk` but due to css styling, it's shown to you in all uppercase.

So, in your assertion, if write your original test like so, it should pass:

```js
  const textView = wrapper.find(Text); // <--- try
  expect(textView.text()).toBe(receivedText); //<---- receivedText is gona be lowercase
```

This is because `receivedText` will be all lowercase.

#### Adding `...` at the end when string is too long

```js
function handleLongString(str, desiredLength){
   return str.length > desiredLength ? str.slice(0,desiredLength) + "..." : str;
}
```

Then you can use this in your code like so:

```html
<Text>{ handleLongString(text) }</Text>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, 1.you can't call 'text()', 2. I get Expected value:    "TRADE-IN ELIGIBLE"
    Received function: [Function children]

Comment: Can you try `props().children` instead as per the 3 approach in my answer

Comment: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'TextProps'

Comment: And one last time, could you try the 4th approach as well..

Comment: Thanks bro, but i still get "Property 'children' does not exist on type 'TextProps'"

Comment: I have a feeling that because you are turning it into uppercase using CSS, the actual text rendered in the DOM will still be lowercase. Hence the failing of your test. Can you try using your original check and test `expect(textView.text()).toBe(receivedText)` and this should pass..

Comment: I get this:
    Expected: "TRADE-IN ELIGIBLE"
    Received: "trade-in eligible", In react native it isn't CSS, and all the 
styles come together so maybe there is no way to check the rendered text

Comment: What i am saying is if you use `receivedText`, your test will pass because `receivedText` is all lowercase and all lowercase is what is getting rendered. So, if you try `expect(textView.text()).toBe(receivedText)` and make sure to use `receivedText` in the `toBe` assertion, you test should pass

Comment: Yes i get you thanks and do you know how can I handle the 3 dots when we have long string?

Comment: see my updated answer for handling `...` at the end of the string.

Comment: bro i know how to write ... dots the numberOfLines={1} does it for me and it work in the component , i just asked how can i test it, because I tried to test it and enter  'trade-in eligable aaaaa'; and expect to 'trade-in eligible...' but it still show me that the receiving is' trade-in eligable aaaaa';